# Is it possible to normalize a python array (containing some NaN values) by just ignoring the NaN values?

Tags: arrays, json, numpy

I have a numpy array which I want to normalize. But this array also contains few NaN values. So I used following code to mask the array and then normalize.

```
my_array_masked = np.ma.array(my_array, mask=np.isnan(my_array))
norm = np.linalg.norm(my_array_masked)
my_array_normalized = my_array_masked/norm
```

It normalizes the array but I have to send the numpy array to create a json file. In that case it causes the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type MaskedConstant is not JSON serializable
```

Is there any way ignore or overlook the NaN values and normalize the array without masking?

Comment: You can use `json.dumps(my_array_normalized.tolist())`. I am no sure that you normalization using masked arrays works. What is the value of `norm`? If `my_array` contains nan values `norm` also will be nan and your normalization doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply perform the operation on values that are not nan

```
norm = np.linalg.norm(x[~np.isnan(x)])
my_array_normalized = my_array / norm if (norm != 0.) else my_array
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Alexandre worked. I also found another solution which is a bit straight forwarded derived from mathematical equation.

```
norm = np.sqrt(np.nansum(np.square(my_array)))
my_array_normalized = my_array/norm
```

It returns normalized array which also contains NaN values and do not causes any issue to add in the josn files.